# Use default value for Scala trait or abstract class in a case class that implements it

Tags: scala, abstract-class, traits

Is there a way to get a version of this code to use the default value defined in the trait?

```scala
trait A {      // alternately `abstract class A`
 def x: String
 def y: Int = 1
}

final case class B(x: String, y: Int) extends A

val b = B("ok") // -> errors out
// I'd like this to turn into a B("ok", 1), 
// by using the default y value from A, but this doesn't work
// and similarly something like
object B {
 def apply(x: String): B = {B(x, A.y)}
} 
// doesn't work either
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you are not providing anything else than that code, I can only suggest how to make it compile but I don't think the design is exactly good.

For the first approach

```scala
trait A {
  def x: String
  def y: Int = 1
}

object DefaultA extends A {
  def x = ??? // you need something here, which means a default impl for this singleton
}

final case class B(x: String, override val y: Int = DefaultA.y) extends A

val b = B("ok") // this will compile
```

For the second case

```scala
trait A {
  def x: String
  def y: Int = 1
}

final case class B(x: String, override val y: Int) extends A

object B {
  def apply(x: String): B =
    // here you create an anonymous instance of the trait but again 
    // you have to provide an implementation for the other method
    B(x, (new A { override def x: String = ??? }).y)

}
```

If method `x` and `y` has no relation, you could use in different traits/classes/singletons

Comment: Yeah, both of those are clever, but I agree each option feels wrong. I don't want to override `y` in the definiton of `B`--I want to accept the default value and make it concrete, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MichaelK Technically, since `val`s in constructor argument's list take values from... well, constructor parameters, what you can call for is impossible - you create values which you will pass into constructor THEN pass them THEN you instantiate these values as `val`s in the constructor's body, THEN you run super constructor (which means that your `A.y` is computed after `B.y` has been initialized with `y`) and then you are initalizing vals from the body of a class/trait/etc. Default values for a constructor are basically static methods so they cannot access values created in super constructor

Comment: At least that's the semantic that Scala is modelling, because internally, bytecode has to do whatever JVM dictates, so `B.y` will be instantiated with `A.y` although with a values computed without an access to `A.y`. Nonetheless, the intuition still holds, and even on bytecode level default method usage in your example would generate `new B(x, B.apply$default$2())`, so trick like the one used by @GastónSchabas is rather necessary (at least if you are adamant on making that `def y` non-abstract).